# Cannot start MySQL server (windows)

Tags: mysql, windows

I've just installed MySQL for the first time, and I'm having problems when starting my server. This is how I'm trying to start my server:

```
mysqld --console
```

and this is the output:

```
2021-02-06T13:14:22.471410Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 5272
2021-02-06T13:14:22.473472Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-02-06T13:14:22.473529Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-02-06T13:14:22.473661Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-02-06T13:14:22.485955Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-02-06T13:14:22.486053Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmmm.... lots of people (students?) struggling to get MySQL going on Windows these days. I wonder if they're following directions from some bogus source?  Can you please [edit] your question to give us a link to the directions you're following? Or use the https://MariaDB.org/  installer--it just works.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the my.ini file, so that MySQL knows where to find all path.

In the default directory you don't have write permissions

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

in thtat my.ini you find

```
# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
```

There Mysql has write permissions